# Make a locally running server use UTC time

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When I am running my meteor server, I try logging a new date to see the information about it.

```
import moment from 'moment';

Meteor.startup(function () {
  const now = moment();
  console.log('Current time:\t', now.format());
  console.log('Offset from UTC:\t', now.utcOffset());
});
```

This logs the following:

```
I20160623-10:07:22.747(-4)? Current time: 2016-06-23T10:07:22-04:00
I20160623-10:07:22.748(-4)? Offset from UTC: -240
```

Is there a way to get my server running as if it were running on UTC time?

Comment: To clarify, is `moment` actually [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: yep, it is, and I have to keep writing characters until it passes the comment limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `export TZ=utc` before you start your server.

Comment: Welcome! You need to run the command everytime you start (or restart) the server. So to make it easier, add it to the pacakge.json commands.